# Animated backround for my android activity using Eclipse and ADT

Tags: android, background, adt, animated

I want to create a background that covers the whole screen of my Activity.
Just like:

```
 android:background="@drawable/background"
```

But I want this background to be `animated` (60 frames), looping and target as many device resolutions as possible.

I tried to do a `drawble` `.jpg` sequence, but the problem is that I use 1920x1080, and the logcat while trying to test it on the emulator, the application crashes, and LogCat gives me en error saying, `not enough memory`

Then I tried to import a `video` of my sequence and set it to play on the background. But I don't know where to put the `video` in my `res` folder and call it from there with `SetVideoPath()`,  in order to  play it.

What is the best approach for an animated background, that covers multiple devices with different resolutions?

@Arun C Thomas

I still get an error in logcat,

OutOfMemoryError

my code is this:

```
package combiolab.biolab;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Renderer graphicsRenderer;

    //public static String gl;
    AnimationDrawable anim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

       GLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl);
       myGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);         
       myGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(graphicsRenderer);
    }



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


         <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
            android:id="@+id/gl" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: scale down the bitmap and then display the same. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: you can place the video in the assets folder of the project. Then you can use AssetManager to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)  view,
 then add it like

```
 <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/gl" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>
```

In `onCreate()` implement Renderer like

```
GLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl);
    myGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);         
    myGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(graphicsRenderer);
```

Comment: Where do I put that piece of XML?